# Disabling DataFrame dimensions printing

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas prints DataFrame dimensions at the last line after the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__
print pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
```

Out:

```
0.13.0
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4

[2 rows x 2 columns]      <- dimensions
```

How to disable the printing of the DataFrame's dimensions? I searched for a set_option but couldn't find any relevant one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, I don't think you can, at least not without monkeypatching `DataFrame`. The magic happens in `DataFrame.__unicode__`:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    """
    Return a string representation for a particular DataFrame

    Invoked by unicode(df) in py2 only. Yields a Unicode String in both
    py2/py3.
    """
    buf = StringIO(u(""))
    if self._info_repr():
        self.info(buf=buf)
        return buf.getvalue()

    max_rows = get_option("display.max_rows")
    max_cols = get_option("display.max_columns")
    if get_option("display.expand_frame_repr"):
        width, _ = fmt.get_console_size()
    else:
        width = None
    self.to_string(buf=buf, max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
                   line_width=width, show_dimensions=True)

    return buf.getvalue()
```

and you see that it passes `show_dimensions=True` without checking any option.  You can call `to_string` yourself, which defaults to `show_dimensions=False`:

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
>>> print df.to_string()
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>>
```

ISTM there's no reason not to have a `display.show_dimensions` option.

Comment: want to do a PR for that?

Comment: @Jeff: I have one almost ready, tests and all, but the str/unicode difference between `repr(df)` and `df.to_string()` is giving me a bit of a headache.  Will discuss @GH.